# Total number of bytes read/written by a Linux process and its children

Tags: linux, io, process-accounting

I would like to print the total number of bytes read/written by a Linux process. For example, I run

```
gcc -c a.c
```

and would like to see how many bytes in total did GCC, including its children, request from the Linux kernel and how many bytes they sent to the kernel.

Incomplete solutions to this problem are:

- The fields `rchar` and `wchar` in `/proc/PID/io` show the number of read/written bytes so far. It does not account for child processes. It is lost as soon as the process terminates.
- A tool such as `strace` can be used to print out the syscalls of a process and its children (such as: `read`, `write` syscalls), but it is unable to aggregate the number of bytes read/written.

How to print the total number of bytes read/written by a Linux process and its child processes?

Comment: why do you ask, and how would you count bytes in pipe between two child processes .

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch N bytes sent via a pipe between two child processes should be counted as: N bytes written, N bytes read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A little awk, and strace is what you want.

```
strace -e trace=read,write -o ls.log ls
```

gives you a log of the read and write syscalls. Now you can take this log and sum the last column like this

```
cat ls.log | grep read | awk 'BEGIN {FS="="}{ sum += $2} END {print sum}'
```

You might wan't to change the grep to match only a read at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Wouldn't `strace` approach miss the mmap'ed files statistics?

Comment: Gives strange values for me please check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291156/why-rsync-does-not-do-delta-transfer

Comment: How can i make that this work when there are errors or similar (eg `O_NONBLOCK` is set and read would block), where `read()` return -1?

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look to [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/), it is a top-like tool that can display the disk consumption of each process (real time and total written and read).

EDIT:

You can also check [sysstat](https://sysstat.github.io/) which looks very powerfull for monitoring a linux box. According to the documentation :

> Can monitor a huge number of different metrics:
>
> 1. Input / Output and transfer rate statistics (global, per device, per partition, per network filesystem and per Linux task / PID).
> 2. CPU statistics (global, per CPU and per Linux task / PID), including support for virtualization architectures.
> 3. Memory, hugepages and swap space utilization statistics.
> 4. Virtual memory, paging and fault statistics.
> 5. Per-task (per-PID) memory and page fault statistics.
> 6. Global CPU and page fault statistics for tasks and all their children.
> 7. Process creation activity.
> 8. Interrupt statistics (global, per CPU and per interrupt, including potential APIC interrupt sources, hardware and software interrupts).
> 9. Extensive network statistics: network interface activity (number of packets and kB received and transmitted per second, etc.) including
>    failures from network devices; network traffic statistics for IP, TCP,
>    ICMP and UDP protocols based on SNMPv2 standards; support for
>    IPv6-related protocols.
> 10. NFS server and client activity.
> 11. Socket statistics.
> 12. Run queue and system load statistics.
> 13. Kernel internal tables utilization statistics.
> 14. System and per Linux task switching activity.
> 15. Swapping statistics.
> 16. TTY device activity.
> 17. Power management statistics (instantaneous and average CPU clock frequency, fans speed, devices temperature, voltage inputs, USB
>     devices plugged into the system).

And here you will find [some examples of usage](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/) of sar (the main command of the sysstat package).

Comment: iotop is showing the size of data that was read from or written to the disk. I think this is a useful piece of information - but my question is concerned with number of bytes requested from the kernel, which includes data that never hits the disk.

Comment: @Atom : oh, sorry, I didn't notice the fact you wanted to count **all** the bytes exchanged with kernel, not only the disk i/o...

Comment: @Atom : I updated my answer with another tool, which can monitor almost everything.